# Selecting values from python dictionaries and string into new dicts

Tags: python, dictionary

I have sorted map that stores keys and values of a dict:

```
def sorted_map(map):
ms = sorted(map.iteritems(), key=lambda (k,v): (-v,k)) 
return ms
```

It stores the network nodes as keys, and their degrees as values – the output is like this:

```
for line in ms:
    print  line


('Node n', 11)
('Node n+1', 11)
('Node n+2', 11)
```

Values range from ~ 1000 through 0. I need to only select those nodes (keys) that have a value of higher/equal to 10. And preferably store them into a new dict (key:value). Is there a way to do it?

Comment: use `filter` similarly to how you use `sorted`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create a new dict from your original dict items, keeping key/value pairings that  have a value >= 10

```
d = {1:23,2:20,3:10,4:9,5:1}
print({k:v for k,v in d.items() if v >=10})
{1: 23, 2: 20, 3: 10}
```

If you just want a new dict sorting is not required.

Answer (score 1):

dict comprehension from Padraic is a better solution, but just to see what is out there you can use filter and dict functions:

```
def sorted_map(dictionary):
    ms = sorted(dictionary.iteritems(), key=lambda (k, v): (-v, k))
    return ms

star_map = {
    'Node 1': 11,
    'Node 2': 12,
    'Node 3': 9,
}

filtered = filter(lambda x: x[1] >= 10, sorted_map(star_map))

print(dict(filtered))
```

Note: You should not use `map` as a variable name because this is a built-in function.